# Replace special character apostrophe with normal apostrophe

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a field which is getting data that contains a special character type of apostrophe outside of the normal oracle ascii range of 0-127. I am trying to do a replace function on this but it keeps being switched to a ? in the DDL. Looking for another way to do the replace

This works in a query but switches when put in the DDL for a view

```
regexp_replace(field_name,'’',chr(39))
```

switches to

```
regexp_replace(field_name,'?',chr(39))
```

A dump function shows that oracle is storing the apostrophe as three characters of ascii 226,128,153. I tried to write the replace on a concatenation of those but that didn't work either.

Comment: Could you prepare http://sqlfiddle.com? I cannot recreate your case

Comment: Try `regexp_replace(field_name,N'’',chr(39))` (with `N` prefix).

Comment: Do you store the DDL in a file?  If yes, what is the encoding of that file?  What tool do you use to execute the DDL?  You say that it works in a query.  Do you store or run your query differently?

Comment: Which client you use to execute the query? What is your NLS_LANG setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, examine the original data that contains the weird apostrophe. I'm not convinced that it is indeed three characters. Use this:

```
select value
, substr(value, 5, 1) one_character
, ascii(substr(value, 5, 1)) ascii_value
from table;
```

This would isolate the 5th character from a column value and its ascii value. Adjust the 5 to the place where the weird apostrophe is located.

When you have the ascii value, use plain `replace` like this to get rid of it (regexp_replace seems overkill):

```
replace(value, chr(ascii_value_of_weird_apostrophe), chr(39));
```

Comment: That did the trick. This allowed me to correctly isolate and replace the weird apostrophe. Thanks!